# Unsure how to Laravel View should handle database results that can be "grouped"

Tags: php, sql, laravel

(This is applicable to any framework but I'm using Laravel for reference).

The following SQL result `$result` is passed to my View from a Controller.

```
Product | Delivery Method | Priority      | Price
Ham     | Courier         | Low           | $3
Ham     | Courier         | Med           | $4
Ham     | Courier         | High          | $5
Jam     | Shipping        | Low           | $9
Jam     | Aircraft        | High          | $20
Jam     | Courier         | Low           | $3
```

I've always wondered how I can slice up this data and "group" them so that the View can print as follows: (the output is HTML but we'll plaintext for this example)

```
Courier
Low Priority
--all products having low priority under courier e.g.:
Ham     | $3
Jam     | $3

--similarly for:
Med Priority
High Priority

-- then repeat for next method (shipping).
```

- How does one achieve this elegantly?
- Does the slicing code go in the Controller, View or Model?
- Should I use multiple queries instead of one so I avoid having to "slice" stuff?

I've been chopping up my data with nested for loops and using array indexes to store it (i.e. `$result['Courier']['Low']`, `$result['Shipping']['Low']`) in the Controller then sending it out to the View which is a really barbaric way to do things in this day and age, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Calculations in PHP are allways faster that doing multiple queries. PHP is very fast with it's arrays. So, if you cant do one SQL query that results in exactly what you need, do it in PHP and avoid any more queries. Usually, you would have a function in one of your models, that returns exactly data in exactly the form you want to use in your view. Your view should not contain any logic unrelated to layouting stuff.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice, I added my logic in the `View` instead so now I have a bunch of nested `foreach` and `if` statements there instead. I want to upvote your comment but I don't seem to have enough rep to do so...

Comment: No prob, my comment isnt elaborate enough for a real answer, thats why i didnt post it as one ;)
You will have tons of discussion on how much logic to put into your view though. Im a hardliner there and allways opt for the least ammount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is that you query the necessary rows (let's say 50 of them). Then you use `array_filter` or `array_map` to separate them into 2 new arrays. Finally, in your view, you can have 2 loops for each of the new array. `array_filter` or `array_map` logic should be put inside `View` so that the actual templates just render the data

Comment: One could argue though, that your logic is analyzing data and not just rendering it, so you could put it into your model. (As I said, Im a hardliner there;) )

Comment: True, you can put it in your model, that is totally fine. You can even use adapter pattern if you want to go fancier :)